# Angular accessing data sub key issue changing key

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some data:

```
data = [
    {
      title: 'My Title',
      settings: {
        hasfooter: false
      }
    }
  ];
```

I have this function:

```
updateKeyValue(key?: any, value?: any): void {
    this.data[key] = value;
}
```

Now I call it like this:

```
<button (click)="updateKeyValue(data[0].settings.hasfooter, true)">Change</button>
```

My issue is it's not changing the value of `"hasfooter"` ...

How can I fix this?

Comment: Because, in key you also pass value, you need to pass key name, not value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your data is not matching up with the way you are using it.

```
this.data[key] = value;
```

This statement implies that this.data is a dictionary or hash, and is accessed using a string (key).

But with this usage:

```
updateKeyValue(data[0].settings.hasfooter
```

You are now treating "data" as an array. Specifically an array of dictionaries.

so which is it? Is this.data an array or a dictionary? You need to decide what your data is before you start using it.

Maybe what you mean to do is this?

```
(click)="updateKeyValue(0, true)"

updateKeyValue(index: number, value?: any): void {
   this.data[index].settings.hasfooter = value;
}
```